# Getting measured width of a button label

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

Is there a way to get the measured-width of a button label in flex based on its style properties at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant `TextField`, rather than `String`. So for `TextField`, make sure you set the `autoSize` property to something other than `TextFieldAutoSize.NONE`. Then you can simply grab the `width` value.

Answer (score 0):

Not on it's style properties. It does expose regular properties which give this information though.